# Llave primaria compuesta en Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Estoy haciendo una práctica en la cual tengo una base de datos con 3 tablas, de las cuales me interesa una que tiene 2 Pk y una FK. 
    He de poder indexar, guardar, mostrar, editar y destruir dicha tabla (se llama hoteles) por medio de APIS. No me funcionan el show, update y destroy. La tabla en cuestión dispone de 2 PK (id_ciudad y nombre) y al hacer un show o update, no logro poder hacer bien la relación. El código que uso seria este:

```
para show:

    public function show($id_ciudad, $nombre)
    {
        $hotel= Hotel::with('ciudad')->where('id_ciudad',
                            '=',intval($id_ciudad))
                            ->where('nombre','=',$nombre)
                            ->first();

        return new HotelesResource($hotel);
    }

Para update:

 public function update(Request $request, Hotel $hotel)
    {

        $hotel= Hotel::with('ciudad')->where('id_ciudad',
                            '=',intval($id_ciudad))
                            ->where('nombre','=',$nombre)
                            ->first();


        try
        {
            $hotel->save();
            $respuesta =(new HotelesResource($hotel))
                        ->response()
                        ->setStatusCode(201);
        }
        catch (QueryException $e)
        {
            $mensaje = Errores::errorMessage($e);
            $respuesta= response()->json(['error'=>$mensaje], 400);


        }

        return $respuesta;
    }


Es la forma que se me ocurria, pero vamos que evidentemente me fallan cosas y no logro verlo claro.
En la clase Hotel sería así (por si sirve de referencia)

class Hotel extends Model
{
    protected $table='hoteles';
    public $primaryKey=['id_ciudad', 'nombre'];
    public $incrementing = false;
    public $timestamps=false;


    public function ciudad()
        {
        //el belongs to es para declarar la parte 1
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Ciudad', 'id_ciudad');
    }

    public function cadena()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Cadena', 'cif');
    }

Gracias
```

Comment: Nunca he probado estas opciones asi que solo las dejo a tu considetación, espero sean útiles [primer opción](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31415213/how-i-can-put-composite-keys-in-models-in-laravel-5)

Answer (score 0):

Cómo puedes leer en la [documentación oficial](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions), Laravel espera que:

- Los modelos tengan solo una llave primaria
- Que la llave primaria tenga el nombre de `id`

Entonces para este caso no es la mejor de las ideas tener una llave primaria compuesta.

**OPCIONES**

- Crea una sola llave primaria por cada tabla con un tipo int o bigint
- Puedes colocarle el nombre que deses pero debes declararlo en el modelo
  *La propiedad nombre colócala como:

  - UNIQUE
  - Puedes colocarle un índice en la migración a esta columna para mejorar el rendimiento en la búsqueda de valores

Comment: El problema es que la base de datos no es mia.. y justamente quieren que trabajemos con tablas que tengan multiples PK, de ahí el problema. Entiendo lo que dices por eso.

Comment: Entiendo, al momento no tengo entonces respuesta así que suerte esperemos alguien más de solución

Comment: @Tolken encontré algunas *posibles soluciones* te las dejo como comentarios en tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

No me ha pasado pero podrías intentar declarar

```
protected $primary_key = 'id_de_tabla';
```

en el modelo

Answer (score 0):

En la `DB` puedes tener `n PK's` si deseas, pero en el modelo para `Laravel` solo declara 1

```
class Hotel extends Model{
    protected $table='hoteles';
    public $primaryKey="id_hotel";
    public $timestamps=false;
    ...
}
```

La razon de una unica llave primaria `PK` es por esto

```
    public function show($id_hotel) {
        $hotel= Hotel::with('ciudad')->find($id_hotel);
        return $hotel;
    }
```

que automaticamente te devuelve un objeto `JSON`

Puedes probarlo en un ruta aparte

```
Route::get("hotel/show/{id_hotel}","HotelControl@show");
```

Comment: Gracias! Al final en la ruta he declarado introducir dos parámetros y ahora si me funciona el show. Voy a probar con el update.